# How can I see the mouse coordinate in Flash Professional IDE?

Tags: flash-cs6, flash-ide

I need to know where my mouse is so that I can translate the UI into code. Does Flash Professional IDE support this?

If not, what is the best solution to this need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Window menu, select Info. The Info panel shows the current x and y values of the mouse.

If you select an object on the stage, the Info panel (and the Properties panel) will display the object's x and y values.